# How can I get multiple characters from a string?

Tags: java, string, char

I'm trying to get the 5th, 6th and 7th digits from a list of digits.

E.g. I want to get the year out of the variable `dateofbirth`, and save it as a separate variable called `dob`, as an `int`.

Here is what I have:

```
int dateofbirth = 17031989
String s = Integer.toString(dateofbirth);
int dob = s.charAt(5);
```

What would I have to put in the parentheses after `s.charAt` to get a few digits in a row?

Comment: Just a general note: Storing a birth date as an integer in the form given by you is just plain wrong. Store it as a string, a `Date` object, a number of days since some starting date, or anything that makes sence. But don't use a number which requires string-formatting in a certain radix to make any sense.

Answer (score 6):

No need for the string conversion:

```
int dateofbirth = 17031989;
System.out.println(dateofbirth%10000); //1989
```

If you did want to do it as a string, then the [substring()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) method would be your friend. You'd also need to use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert the string back into an integer. Taking a character value as an integer will give you the ASCII value of that character, not an integer representing that character!

Comment: nice use of the mod operator.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [String.substring](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) (untested):

```
int dateofbirth = 17031989;
String s = Integer.toString(dateofbirth);
String year = s.substring(4, 8);
int yearInt = Integer.parseInt(year);
```

Answer (score 2):

`s.substring(5)` will give you everything starting from index `5`. You could also give a second argument to indicate where you want the substring to end.

Answer (score 1):

If you are handling dates, you could use SimpleDateFormat and Calendar to pull out the year:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy"); 
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(formatter.parse(Integer.toString(dateofbirth)));
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

you do:

```
String s = String.valueOf(dateofbirth);
int yourInt = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(startIndex,length))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out String.substring() !

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

This approach won't work for several reasons:

1. s.charAt(5) will give you the ASCII code of the 6th character (which is not 9).
2. There is no method to get several chars

If you want to extract 1989 from this string you should use substring and then convert this string into an Integer using Integer.valueOf()

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer.parseInt(s.subString(4))
```

Answer (score -1):

From the JRE documentation: [`getChars`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getChars%28int,%20int,%20char%5b%5d,%20int%29)

Comment: What about writing one or two more sentences about this?

Comment: Because if I can answer a question with four words, using six is not an improvemnent. Everything else the poster could ask, he can find in the link.